# how to set initial value to combobox in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

If I want to set the value of the combobox I have tried this:

controllercode:

```
 $scope.streettypeMockData = [{
    name: 'Street',
    value: 'Street'
  }, {
    name: 'Avenue'
  }, {
    name: 'Crescent'
  }, {
    name: 'Drive'
  }, {
    name: 'Road'
  }, {
    name: 'Highway'
  }];

  var sel = "Street";
  var selectedValue = {
    name: sel
  };
  $scope.streetTypeSelected = selectedValue;
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work? see also http://plnkr.co/edit/4ISL8A1cNGCtafsc0leX?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.streetTypeSelected = $scope.streettypeMockData[0];`

Comment: @HanssieTeeuwen Take a look at my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a few issues:

- The `ng-options` select the name, while the `ng-model` points to an object. Better use `streetType as streetType.name for streetType in streettypeMockData` to select the entire object.
- In this case, the initial value will not be honoured because Angular will try to compare objects by reference; use `track by`.

The full `<select>` should be:

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="streetTypeSelected"
      ng-options="streetType as streetType.name for streetType in streettypeMockData track by streetType.name">
```

See [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VExU8onRxuEeCzNqYbf8?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) like this

```
<select ng-init="streetTypeSelected = streettypeMockData[0]" class="form-control" ng-model="streetTypeSelected" ng-options="streetType.name for streetType in streettypeMockData">
  </select>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/67/)**

Also you can do Like as shown below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.streettypeMockData = [
        {name: 'Street', value: 'Street'},
        {name: 'Avenue'},
        {name: 'Crescent'},
        {name: 'Drive'},
        {name: 'Road'},
        {name: 'Highway'}
    ];
    $scope.streetTypeSelected = $scope.streettypeMockData[0];
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/66/)**

Also take a look at this

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: how do you calculate the position 3 in  $scope.streetTypeSelected = $scope.streettypeMockData[3] then? It is missing the 'selectedvalue' input which is a string "Street" or "Drive"

Comment: If you want Street to be print as default you should use `$scope.streetTypeSelected = $scope.streettypeMockData[0]`, if you want Drive the use `$scope.streetTypeSelected = $scope.streettypeMockData[3]`...etc